# Tomcat global connection pooling getting error

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, database-connection, connection-pooling

I deployed three web application in tomcat web container.

My server.xml file configuration is :

```
<Service name="app1">
   <Connector port="8081" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
   <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="app1"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
      </Host>
   </Engine>
</Service>
<Service name="app2">
   <Connector port="8082" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
   <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="app2"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
      </Host>
   </Engine>
</Service>
<Service name="app3">
   <Connector port="8083" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
   <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="app3"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
      </Host>
   </Engine>
</Service>
```

I added this connection pool setting in context.xml file.

```
<Resource name="test" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="root" password="root"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"/>
```

In first application "app1" database connection working fine but in second application "app2" I am getting this error.

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp].
```

My java code is :

```
public static Connection getConnection() {
    Context initContext;
    DataSource dataSource;
    Connection con=null;
    try {
        initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        dataSource = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("test");
        con=dataSource.getConnection();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        LOG.error(e);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOG.error(e);
    }
```

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that this will work but  I use it as

```
InitialContext initCtx = new InitialContext();
return (DataSource)initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/"+jndiDb);
```

//jndiDB is defined in my case as **jndi/TestDB** //TestDB is the name of the database

In context.xml, I have

```
<Resource  .... url="jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.101.124:1433;  name="jdbc/TestDB" databaseName="TestDB" />
```